# ¿Cómo puedo evitar crear un indice para cada objeto en mi array?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Lo que intento hacer es crear una mini app que me permitar generar una fórmula química a partir de los datos obtenidos por el usuario. En primera instancia es detectar que simbolo químico eligió, luego, ver si ese simbolo químico tiene o no una valencia de dicho elemento, luego de eso todo se me hace más sencillo porque se trata de jugar con los estilos de manera dinámica.

Espero hacerme entender con la pregunta. Trato de evitar   crear: metales[0].simbolo,metales[1].simbolo, metales[2].simbolo, etc.

Si en tal caso mi array puede tener más objetos en el futuro, que estructura de control me puede ayudar a evitar esto? Intenté hacerlo con el bucle for pero al recorrer el arry, el alerta "alert('El símbolo fue encontrado');" lo hace tres veces (el número de objetos en el array), con lo cual, manda las tres alertas en vez de una sola donde encuentra la coincidencia.
¿Debo de usar lodash o underscore? 
¿Está mal planteado el objeto?
¿Debo de usar indexOf? Muchas gracias!

```
 function preguntar() {

        var metales = [
           {
               'nombre': 'Litio',
               'simbolo': 'Li',
               'valencia': 1
           },
           {
               'nombre': 'Sodio',
               'simbolo': 'Na',
               'valencia': 1
           },
           {
               'nombre': 'Potasio',
               'simbolo': 'K',
               'valencia': 1
           }     
        ];
        var pregunta = prompt("Indica el símbolo");

            if(pregunta == metales[0].simbolo || pregunta == metales[1].simbolo || pregunta == metales[2].simbolo ) {
                alert('El símbolo fue encontrado');
            }else{
                alert('El símbolo no fue encontrado');
            }

         }
        preguntar();
```

Comment: Mencionas un bucle for, pero no veo ninguno en tu pregunta

Comment: @Mariano Claro en el ejemplo no lo coloqué porque no encuentro la forma de que me de el resultado esperado y quería ver de que forma lo podía plantear mejor.

Comment: por más que no funcione, ayuda ver qué estás intentando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es evitar recorrer el array para acceder al objeto cuya propiedad satisfaga tu condición, debes cambiar la estructura en la que almacenas esa información. En vez de un `Array` utilizar un `Objeto`, cuya clave sea el valor de la propiedad a la que quieres acceder. Por lo tanto, en tu caso para evitar recorrer el array y tener un acceso rápido al valor que buscas, haría algo así:

```js
var metales = {
  'Li' : {
    'nombre': 'Litio',
    'valencia': 1
  },
  'Na' : {
    'nombre': 'Sodio',
    'valencia': 1
  },
  'K' : {
    'nombre': 'Potasio',
    'valencia': 1
  }
};

console.log('Metal encontrado : Símbolo(K) -> Nombre ' + metales['K'].nombre + '; Valencia 1? ' + !!(metales['K'].valencia == 1) );
```

Nota la sintaxis : `metales['K']` para acceder al objeto que deseas. 
Eliminé la propiedad `simbolo` de los objetos, porque realmente ya no haría falta.

Comment: Algo así intento hacer pero me explico. Intento que luego que se consiga dicho simbolo, verifique si ese obejto tenga valencia o no. Quero tomar K y ver si su valencia es 1 en un prompt.

Comment: Mira la edición.

Comment: @JoseHermosillRodrigo estoy por dar con lo que busco pero que sintaxis del if ese que no conocía?

Comment: Y por cierto, hay elementos que tienen más de dos valencias como se sabe. Cómo puedo almacenar que por ejemplo otro metal como el Fe tiene valencia 2 y 3. Debo de colocarlo como:  `'valencia': [2,3 ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

unos pequeños cambios. Prueba esto:

```
        var metales = [
           {
               'nombre': 'Litio',
               'simbolo': 'Li',
               'valencia': 1
           },
           {
               'nombre': 'Sodio',
               'simbolo': 'Na',
               'valencia': 1
           },
           {
               'nombre': 'Potasio',
               'simbolo': 'K',
               'valencia': 1
           }
        ];

        function preguntar(pregunta) {
            for (i = 0; i < metales.length;i++)
            {
                if (pregunta.toLowerCase() == metales[i].simbolo.toLowerCase())
                    return metales[i];
            }
            return null;
        }

        function prueba(){
            var simbolo= prompt("Indica el símbolo");
            var metal= preguntar(simbolo);
            if(metal==null)  alert('El símbolo no fue encontrado');
            else  alert('El elemento fue encontrado: ' + metal.nombre +
 ', Simbolo: ' + metal.simbolo +
 ', Valencia: ' + metal.valencia);
        }
```

1.Primero creo un boton en el Html de la página

```
 <button type="button" onclick="prueba()">PRUEBA</button>
```

2.Ese botón cuando click , llama a prueba();

3.Prueba saca un dialogo para preguntar al usuario el símbolo.

4.obtenido el símbolo llamo a la función preguntar(simbolo)

5.preguntar hace la primera parte de la miniapp que es recorrer la tabla de elementos para encontrar un simbolo y si lo encuentra devuelve el elemento y si no null.

La tabla metales esta formada con elementos que podemos llamar "metal"
podemos añadir tantos campos de información como queramos: la densidad el pm... lo que se necesite que sean valores constantes.

Siendo una tabla discreta en principio vale descrita tal y como está, en una hora o menos te has rellenado la tabla entera incluso con algun campo más, animo!!!

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="prueba()">PRUEBA</button>

Comment: Hola @AlbertoF.L que función cumple el return null;

Comment: Hola @Alberto. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! ¿Podrías explicar con más detalle cómo esto resuelve al problema de la pregunta? Quizás una breve explicación ayudaría. La idea es sumar respuestas con la mayor calidad posible

Comment: Hola @Mariano quizás sea muy complejo para mi aun. Lo que intento hacer es crear una mini app que me permitar generar una fórmula química a partir de los datos obtenidos por el usuario. En primera instancia es detectar que simbolo químico eligió, luego, ver si ese simbolo químico tiene o no una valencia de dicho elemento, luego de eso todo se me hace más sencillo porque se trata de jugar con los estilos de manera dinámica.

Comment: @MarcAnt si esa información es relevante, debería ir en la pregunta, no en un comentario

Comment: El valor null lo utilizo en

Comment: if(metal==null)  alert('El símbolo no fue encontrado');

Comment: Esto es muy sencillo. los pasos son los siguientes: